# Remove RVM, Ruby and gems completely?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, rvm

I had to downgrade Rails and now the gems, the versions, and everything, are completely messed up and I feel like jumping from my window.

I just want to destroy everything related with RVM, Ruby and gems to make sure I make a 100% clean reinstallation.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Linux and installed as regular user ? Than all you need to do is:

```
rm -Rf ./.rvm
rm -Rf ./.gem
rm -f ./.gemrc
```

You can also check ~/.bashrc and ~/.bash_profile files for lines like this:

```
PATH=$PATH:$HOME/.rvm/bin # Add RVM to PATH for scripting
[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM into a shell session *as a function*
```

This should be enough. If you've installed it in some custom way then try this:

```
$ rvm list # to see what version you have installed
$ rvm gemdir # to see where are gemfiles located
```

There is something like `rvm remove` as well but, if you want to just remove all, than it's not very interesting I think.

Answer (score 3):

If you have installed everything via `rvm` a simple

```
rvm implode
```

will remove all traces of `rvm` including rubies and gems. Even (as far as I remember, I'm not testing it right now) the shell files are updated.

Answer (score 1):

`rvm implode` which removes all ruby installations rvm manages, everything in ~/.rvm