# Can't install rails 3.2.9: Failed to build gem native extension

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I [just cleaned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22769949/remove-rvm-ruby-and-gems-completely/22770044#22770044) rvm and ruby and reinstalled it. I am trying to install rails but I get this error:

> gem install rails -v 3.2.9

```
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing rails:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        /usr/bin/ruby1.9.1 extconf.rb
/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require': cannot load such file -- mkmf (LoadError)
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from extconf.rb:1:in `<main>'


Gem files will remain installed in /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/json-1.8.1 for inspection.
Results logged to /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/json-1.8.1/ext/json/ext/generator/gem_make.out
```

And if I run `bundle install` with my `Gemfile` which has `rails 3.2.9`  and a few more gems I get this error:

```
An error occurred while installing json (1.8.1), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install json -v '1.8.1'` succeeds before bundling.
```

Guess what. Running the suggested command gives me another error:

```
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing json:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        /usr/bin/ruby1.9.1 extconf.rb
/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require': cannot load such file -- mkmf (LoadError)
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from extconf.rb:1:in `<main>'


Gem files will remain installed in /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/json-1.8.1 for inspection.
Results logged to /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/json-1.8.1/ext/json/ext/generator/gem_make.out
```

Comment: What is your operating system?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Possible duplicate of:

- [Unable to install gem - Failed to build gem native extension - cannot load such file -- mkmf (LoadError)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13767725/unable-to-install-gem-failed-to-build-gem-native-extension-cannot-load-such/13767801#13767801)
- [`require': no such file to load -- mkmf (LoadError)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7645918/require-no-such-file-to-load-mkmf-loaderror)

---

**Depending on your ruby version**, run:

```
sudo apt-get install ruby1.9.1-dev
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple google search points to this earlier stackoverflow question:

[Why do I get an error installing the JSON gem in Ubuntu?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11058952/why-do-i-get-an-error-installing-the-json-gem-in-ubuntu)

> Installing the ruby1.9.1-dev package should fix this for you:
>
> `sudo apt-get install ruby1.9.1-dev`